# Regular Expression for Address/Zip/City&State

Tags: ruby, regex, search

Anybody have an example of a regular expression that matches for address, zip, or [city,state]?

**Update:**
Admittedly, this is a weak question because I don't have enough information regarding user behavior at this point to really qualify the parameters of the problem. Here is what I'm trying to do though:

Create a search function that depending on what information has been entered in chooses one of two divergent paths, the first being address proximity search and the second being organization name search.

It is proving a difficult problem to solve, so any input out there, besides .* (okay, okay I deserved that) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yep, `.*` matches them. But kidding aside, you should provide examples, good and bad trials, etc.

Comment: This is a difficult problem since addresses are extremely variable. There is no single regex that can handle this reliably (except maybe `.*` :)). Can you define your problem more specifically?

Comment: Zabba - USA. @Tim and Zsolt: updated the question with some specifics.

Comment: The USPS has APIs for validating addresses. It doesn't use regex, it checks the address against the USPS's database. https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out geocoder (http://www.rubygeocoder.com/). It will get lat/long from text input. What you could do for your search is first try to match organization names, and then try to match locations.

Luckily google figure out how to do proximity searches a while ago